# How to get Windows to recognize physical wi-fi switch?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, wifi-driver

I installed Windows 8.1 in my laptop (Lenovo IdeaPad Z570) and all the needed drivers listed [here](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&DocID=HT072735).

Everything's working fine (even the "special" physical buttons*). The only problem I'm facing now is getting the Wi-Fi to work.

There is a physical switch* that should turn on/off the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth adapter. The issue is that it's only switching the Bluetooth, and I cannot use my wireless connection.

I tried looking for an option to turn it on from Windows but it seems like the adapter is not physically "activated". I also tried installing Win7 drivers but it doesn't change a thing.

Any ideas?

*I added a couple of images to show what I'm talking about but I guess I need more reputation points to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all the available drivers but nothing worked. I decided to reinstall Windows 7, installed the same drivers (but, of course, for this version) and got it working. Then, I installed Windows 8 **as and update** and I could use my WiFi since the beginning.

Hope this helps someone in the futue.